# It is possible to continue processing after "No criteria—just execute the actions"?

Tags: process-builder

Is it possible to create a Process Builder that first executes actions with no criteria (by using "No criteria—just execute the actions" or some other means), then goes to next block ("false" condition) to execute next decision/actions?

I have just been creating separate Process Builder processes when the first thing I need to do is always do something. However, I prefer to use Process Builder more as a dispatcher per object, where there are immediately actions and criteria based actions.

Is it possible to have a single Process Builder process that always executes actions as the first step, then continues to process after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can. Just click the stop sign and select "Evaluate the next criteria".

[image: Process Builder screenshot]

[image: Process Builder screenshot]

[image: Process Builder screenshot]

Comment: Brilliant! I can't believe it has been in-front of my face all this time and I didn't see it. Thank you!